# lower bound of the function f(x) = x^2+x+1?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, time-complexity

> the function is 
>                 f(x) = x^2+x+1
>
> > ```
> >    **Upper Bound**
> >  when x>0,
> >               x^2 >= x^2    
> >   similarly,  x >= x^2   
> >    and,    
> >               1 >= x^2
> > ```

```
    therefore,  f(x)=x^2+x+1  >= x^2+x^2+x^2   (all sufficient large value of x)
                              >= 3x^2     , where c=3 

                           f(x)= O(x^2)
```

> ```
>   **Lower Bound**
>
>         f(x)=x^2+x+1 >= x^2
>                   f(x) = Ω(x^2)
> ```

**>       but can we write it's lower bound as Ω(x) and Ω(1)    because**

> ```
>               f(x)=x^2+x+1  >= x    (all sufficient large value of x)
>                       f(x)  = Ω(x)  ??
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>              f(x)=x^2+x+1 >= 1   (all sufficient large value of x)
>                       f(x)  = Ω(1)   ?????
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely we can write it as w(n) and even w(1). However, this doesn't make sense at all, since we are looking for **the highest Ω**. (Ω would be symboled with small omega rather than this big one to indicate that `c . g(n) < f(n)`. If we use Ω, that means `c . g(n) <= f(n)`).

`c . g(n) < f(n)` means that: there is no constant `c` that enlarges g(n) to be`g(n) = f(n) for all n >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Well it may not be efficient to write  **Ω(1)** or  **Ω(x)**, even though it is correct.  Ω(x) defines an **asymptotically tight lower bound**. So it is better to use the **ω** notation which defines an **asymptotically not tight lower bound**. So in this particular problem **ω(x)** or **ω(1)** better defines the run time complexity than  Ω(x) or  Ω(1).